# python - parse string (which is an array) returned from a web service as array/list

Tags: python, arrays, string, web-services, parsing

I am using

```
httplib.HTTPConnection(self._myurl)
conn.request("GET", "/")
data = conn.getresponse().read()
```

now this URL returns an python type arrays similar to the below:

```
[1,"apple",23,"good"]
[2,"grape",4,"bad"]
```

Now i am getting this result from the service as a string in data. How do i get this result parsed/encoded as array/list straight away without having to dissect it myself and create an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[updated]
Service was actually designed for stream rather than data in bulk. So that is why I was actually getting array of objects instead of array of array objects.

I handled it at javascript side finally using the following logic.

```
1. data = data.replace(']','],')
2. data = '[' + data.rstrip(',') + ']'
3. data = json.loads(data)
```

---

**Reply to the above answer**
Actually it is not, the json will be

```
{"key":[[...],[...]]}
```

I have tried the code and it fails with the following error.

```
...
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 326, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 38 column 119 (char 25 - 4048)
```

Comment: JSON includes arrays, not just objects.

Comment: Yes, and an array would be [],[],[] NOT [][][].

Answer (score 3):

If the server is returning [JSON](http://json.org/) (which it looks like it might be) it is a simple matter of:

```
import json

# ... snip ...

rehydrated_data = json.loads(data)
```